# How do I replace a text box with a drop down populate by web service in fogbugz using greasemonkey script?

Tags: greasemonkey, fogbugz

I want to replace the 'client' field text box in fogbugz when you edit a case to be a drop down instead populated from a separate web service that will keep the client options up to date in our fogbugz. Is this possible? Will the choice they select in the drop down be able to save the same way it would if they had typed it into the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, email us at http://contact.fogcreek.com and get on the FogBugz 7 beta which has the ability to do this with plugins (instead of GM) or even, just with a custom field.

Comment: @Michael Pryor: This answer is not spam IMHO, as it was a question about this product, and since the version you highlight addresses the question. However, it would be even _less_ spam if you were to edit the answer to include an example of how to do what he wants using the beta.

Comment: Huh, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

An off-the-cuff answer:

Yes.  For a first pass, you can implement it by creating the drop-down list on the side, populating it with a GM_xmlHttpRequest, and adding a "onchange" action listener to the drop-down list, which will populate the textfield with the relevant information from the drop-down.  This ensures that fogbugz sees exactly what it wants, in exactly the way it wants to see it.